# Why does the code work depending on statements order

Tags: javascript

The `forEach` below works if it has this order:

```
series.forEach(s => {
        s.color = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][0]
        s.name = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][1]
})
```

But it fails if the order is:

```
series.forEach(s => {
        s.name = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][1]
        s.color = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][0]
})
```

The question is: **why?**

---

Sample code

```js
let series = [
  {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Destapado',
    data: [
      0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Guardado de carpa',
    data: [
      0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Presacado de carpa',
    data: [
      0, 3, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Retapado',
    data: [
      0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Tapado',
    data: [
      0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0
    ]
  }
]

let coloresNombres = {
            'destapado': ['#ec7126', 'Destape'],
            'guardado de carpa': ['#fe9b38', 'Guardado'],
            'presacado de carpa': ['#003a81', 'Sacado'],
            'retapado': ['#2fb9d5', 'Retape'],
            'tapado': ['#00669e', 'Tapado']
        }
series.forEach(s => {
     s.name = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][1]
     s.color = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][0]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're changing the value of `s.name`.

In the "working" example, `s.name` is the same value throughout the function but is changed at the very end:

```
series.forEach(s => {
    s.color = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][0]
    s.name = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][1]
})
```

But in the "non-working" example, `s.name` is changed on the first line and then *used* on the second line:

```
series.forEach(s => {
    s.name = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][1]
    s.color = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][0]
})
```

Since `s.name` has a new value, `s.name.toLowerCase()` has a new value, so `coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()]` will have a new value, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the second second version you are reassigning s.name then using it as a key to coloresNombres.

If we run through one iteration with the following object:

```
{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Destapado',
    data: [
      0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0
    ]
  }
```

when you run

```
s.name = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][1]
```

it changes the object to

```
{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Destape',
        data: [
          0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0
        ]
      }
```

then afterwards it runs

```
 s.color = coloresNombres[s.name.toLowerCase()][0]
```

Where the new name, 'Destape', is not a valid key for coloresNombres.
In the first version it would use Destapado which is a valid key.